# How to connect to Mysql database on XAMPP in AppJS

Tags: node.js, appjs

I am on Linux 32-bit machine and using AppJS for developing desktop application.

After searching for a while,I can't find a way to connect to my Mysql database on XAMPP.

Is it possible to connect or I am wasting my time searching?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appjs-dev/iBYVij7JeHI), it seems like you can use available libraries for node to do this. Like [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).

Also I think you should look into **[this issue](https://github.com/appjs/appjs/issues/393)**.

Quote:

> deskshell is the next generation of appjs. Appjs merges nodejs and
>   chromium's event loop. This is awesome but it means that a long
>   running nodejs operation will stop animations in the browser and it
>   means lots of other unexpected side effects. Solution is to run 2
>   separate binaries (nodejs and chromium) and connect them together
>   using the chrome remote debugging protocol. Deskshell therefore is
>   built in javascript rather than C++ and this makes it much more
>   hackable and quicker to develop. Appjs will be able to be used by
>   deskshell instead of chromium as the "browser" part of the application
>   in the future.

But I **strongly** **suggest** you look into [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). It is used by apps like [Popcorn-Time](https://github.com/popcorn-official/popcorn-app).